# Partial sum of the sequence $\frac{X-n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence:

$S_r = \frac{x-r}{r} $

where $x$ is 2 times the greatest value for r.

How can I calculate the formula of the partial sum of this sequence ?

Comment: Do you mean $S_r$? Is $r \geq 1$?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 yes  r≥1.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 fixed it.

Comment: @guy600 yes......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=1}^R \frac{x-r}{r} = \sum_{r=1}^R x\cdot \frac{1}{r} - 1 = x\cdot\sum_{r=1}^R r^{-1} + \sum_{r=1}^R 1 = xH_R+R$$

where $H_R$ is the $R$-th harmonic number. If $R$ is particularly large, $H_R\approx \log R + \gamma$, where $\gamma \approx 0.57721$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. This brings the estimate of the partial sum for large $R$ to $x\log R + x\gamma + R$.

Comment: Thanks. the values of R that I will need to use won't be greater than 130. Is that large enough to give an accurate estimation using this formula?

Comment: It depends on your idea of "close enough". The error in that estimate is $O(R^{-1})$, which will net you approximately 1 or 2 decimal points of accuracy for $R \approx 100$. Here's a few more terms if you want something more accurate for your smaller $R$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596621/asymptotic-estimate-of-the-sequence-of-harmonic-series-sum-k-1n-frac1

Comment: Is there any formula that doesn't need the harmonic numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Basically any time you have an $r$ in the denominator that doesn't cancel out, you're going to have harmonic numbers, which means there's no closed form expression.

Comment: Of course, if you have exact values of $R$ you want to calculate this for, you can simply calculate it manually, i.e. numerically via a computer program. For example, with WolframAlpha, you can quickly calculate the sum whenever you need to: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+r%3D1+to+R+of+(x-r)%2Fr,+x+%3D+300,+R+%3D+130